# When are integration constants parameters for you to choose, and when are they simply unknowns yet fixed?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

I'm currently viewing a textbook on differential equations. They were demonstrating a introductory example on **reduction of order** where they derived a general solution

The question was:

*Given that $y_1 = e^x$ is a solution of $y''-y=0$ on the interval $(-\infty, \infty)$, use reduction of order to find a second solution $y_2$.*

Eventually, they got to

$$y=u(x)e^x=-\frac{c_1}{2}e^{-x}+c_2 e^x.$$

But then they said **"by picking $c_2=0$ and $c_1=-2$, we obtain the desired second solution $y_2=e^{-x}$."**

> **Question.** How come in this case, we can choose particular values for the integration constants? Sometimes, when we are given initial conditions for different problems the integration constants are not free parameters, but are fixed constants that need to be solved for. Does that mean this method (reduction of order) is not valid for an IVP?

**Link for screenshot from textbook:**

[image]

Comment: Since there are no initial conditions, the parameters $c_1,c_2$ are free.

Comment: It just gets you another independent solution. They picked integration constants to end up with $e^{-x}$ but there is nothing special about that one rather than some combination of both exponentials. In an IVP you could still do this but at the end you would have an algebraic system to solve to find the coefficients.

Comment: @Ian Thanks! So for an IVP, neither $e^x$ nor $e^{-x}$ need to be solutions, but the solution would result from some $c_1, c_2$ in $c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{-x}$ predetermined from initial conditions? I guess I'm still trying to understand the idea behind obtaining another linearly independent solution by assuming the parameters are free, but later using a linear combination of the same solution for an IVP?

Comment: All you're doing is constructing the general solution. In terms of solving an IVP, constructing the general solution allows you to reduce the problem to an algebraic system of equations.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is here

[image]

hence the general solution is $$y=c_1 e^x+c_2 e^{-x}$$

### **************

In addition you can also follow the comment of Inn.